# What does the "Backlog Priority" value represent in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2012 Web Access, you can drag/drop items within your backlog to adjust the priority.  I viewed the history of a work item after I adjusted the backlog, and noticed a peculiar value as my new "Backlog Priority".  Does anyone know what this number represents?  I am curious because of a bigger issue I have with adjusting backlog priorities within a Team backlog also does weird things with the parent (project) backlog.  So if I can figure out what this value represents, I can figure out my other stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now the stack rank field that is used for ordering. The algorithm of how it is updated when you stack rank items using the Product Backlog view of Team Web Access is why you get interesting numbers.

Answer (score 3):

In TFS 2010, it was used to order your Product Backlog and the default value was 1000.  I believe in TFS 11, they have now taken over this value and just adjust it to reflect the order you have specified in the backlog.  In other words, they leave enough space between the backlog priority numbers to allow for new PBI's and the changing of order of any PBI.