# tfs 2012 drag drop in web portal no longer works

Tags: portal

Background:

- new team project with TFS 2012, Agile 6 MSF template
  *Modified the project based on http://roadtoalm.com/2013/01/04/changing-the-product-backlog-in-tfs-2012/
- added a few new fields and added them to the requirements template

Issues:

1. I can't drag and drop user stories or tasks in the web portal to assign stories to users on the iteration backlog.
2. I can right click on tasks to assign to developers, but not user stories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you were receiving a specific error when attempting to drag and drop, so I'm not sure if this answer will help.  In our case, we were getting this error when dragging and dropping:

*TF237165: Team Foundation could not update the work item because of a validation error on the server. This may happen because the work item type has been modified or destroyed, or you do not have permission to update the work item.*

The solution in our case was that we had existing decimal values (like 0.09) in the Stack Rank field.  The Stack Rank field is what TFS uses to order the fields (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10844399/1001100)).  After we cleared out the Stack Rank field, it worked.